# Retrieving local variable value

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have this function written by other. How can I retrieve the value of 'options' below? I believe it is a local variable.

```
function [ew1, Periodogram] = dest_modified3(x,m)
n = length(x);
%x2 = dmtrend(x);   % detrended data    (demeaning is done in univariate_d!) 

%m = fix(n^0.6);        % m is the number of frequencies used in estimation.

options = optimset('fminbnd');

%dw = fminbnd('whittle',-1,3,options,x,m);      % LW estimate
[ew1,Periodogram] = fminbnd('ewhittle',-2,4,options,x,m,0); % ELW estimate
%ew2 = fminbnd('ewhittle',-2,4,options,x,m,1);  % FELW estimate
%ew3 = fminbnd('ewhittle',-2,4,options,x2,m,1); % FELW w/ detrending
%[felw1, Periodogram] = felw2st_modified(x,m,3,10);                     

% 2stage FELW 
    %felw2 = felw2st(x2,m,3,10);                        % 2stage      FELW w/ detrending

% fprintf(1,'Number of observations     %7i \n', n);
% fprintf(1,'Number of frequencies used %7i \n\n', m);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: LW estimator                                %7.5f  \n', dw);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: exact LW estimator                          %7.5f  \n', ew1);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: feasible ELW estimator                      %7.5f  \n', ew2);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: feasible ELW estimator with detrending      %7.5f  \n', ew3);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: 2-step feasible ELW estimator               %7.5f  \n', felw1);
% fprintf(1,'Estimate of d: 2-step feasible ELW estimator w/ detrending %7.5f  \n', felw2);
```

Comment: Modify the first line: `function [ew1, Periodogram, options] = dest_modified3(x,m)`

Comment: options = 

                   Display: 'notify'
               MaxFunEvals: 500
                   MaxIter: 500
                    TolFun: []
                      TolX: 1.0000e-04
               FunValCheck: 'off'
                 OutputFcn: []
                  PlotFcns: []
           ActiveConstrTol: []
                 Algorithm: []
                        ...........

Comment: Above is the output. It does not work. I'm really new to matlab or any programming. I need the value of the input 'options' that is used in 'fminbnd' above. Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting options to be?  What do you mean "It does not work"?

Comment: Have you read http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/ref/optimset.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, grantnz. I'm working on it